# sql column default value with functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, html, default-value

I am new to SQL, but I am trying to set up a database in the html5 sql storage using a javascript in a jquery $(document).ready statement.  I have been testing in Chrome, and firefox, but firefox does not work at all, and the problem that I have in chrome, is that I can set up a default value just fine if it is a static value, but when I try to use a function, things do not turn out so well, I think that this code only calls the default function once when I actually want it to call the function every time. However, when I try to do that the function ErrorDB gets called.
here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var db;
try{if(window.openDatabase){
    db =openDatabase("fetchnotes", "1.0","fetchnotesDB",1000000);
    if (!db) {alert("failed to load database on disk"); return;};   
    }     
            else{
       alert("could not open database.");
       return;
    }

}catch(err){alert("error "+err); return;}
db.transaction(initializeDB, errorDB);
});
function initializeDB(tx){
    tx.executeSql('Drop TABLE IF EXISTS NOTES');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS'+
    ' NOTES(ID int primary key,NoteText, LastModified Date NOT NULL DEFAULT "'  
            +defaultLastModified()+ '")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO NOTES (ID, NoteText) VALUES (1, "make a better database") ');
}

function errorDB(tx,err)
{
    alert("error "+err);        
}
function defaultLastModified()
{
    var result= new Date();
    return result;      
}
```

Okay I found something of a solution for the problem, which is that That I had an incorrect data type as well as a few other things. the for corrected code is here:

```
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"+
    " NOTES(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,NoteText TEXT ," +
    "LastModified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT (datetime('now','localtime')));");
```

you technically do not need the 'localtime', leaving it out means that the time would be in GMT which is standard for SQL.  However, I still do not know how to in general get a user defined function to be the default value, which is still my main question.

Comment: Will it be a public application ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things I think are wrong.

1. I'm pretty sure a JS Date-object won't fit in a SQL-query (`... "' + defaultLastModified() + "' ...`).
2. If it would fit, it wouldn't work as you think either: `defaultLastModified()` will return `now`, so when you add a record in 2 weeks, it'll still contain `now` (so 2 weeks prior to adding the record).
3. Haven't dates (in SQL) got a default value by default (that'll automatically fill in the real `now`, always)?

Comment: 1. I am not sure if it is as a Date still or just a string, but this code will fill in the database with what looks like a Date.
2. you are right I also do not think that this code works the way that I want it to.
3. as far as I can tell, there is no default Date value being called automatically, All the things I have tried looking for something like that have left the LastModified field blank.
Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that executeSql is only supported on WebKit based browsers, thus it will not work in Firefox or IE. I would suggest looking for another method to write to a browser side database.

For WebKit browsers (Chrome, Safari) you may want to try using a semicolon to close the SQL statement.

Example

> tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NOTES(ID int primary key,NoteText, LastModified Date NOT NULL DEFAULT "' + defaultLastModified() + '");');